# Getting all HostSystem references by Datacenter with a single request

Tags: java, api, vmware, vsphere

I'm connecting to a vCenter using vSphere API 5.5.

So far, I'm getting list of all `HostSystem` references along with some of their properties using `PropertyCollector`. What I'd like to do is have an information about the `Datacenter` (name) each `HostSystem` belongs to.

I was able to fetch all the `Datacenter` and `HostSystem` MORs using traversal specifications, but the result I get is sort of "flat": there is no structure or reference that could let me now which `HostSystem` belongs to which `Datacenter`.

I feel like I'm looking at this the wrong way.
Is there a better approach to fetching this kind of info?

Answer (score 0):

I want to know what cluster a host belongs to and do it like this: Get all clusters, for each cluster get the hosts that are part of it; for every host X I find in cluster Y, store that host X belongs to cluster Y.

Maybe this works for datacenters, too.

Comment: Sure it does, it just means that the client has to hit the service the number of datacenters + 1, :) and I was hoping there was a way to do it with a single request... Edited the question's title to reflect that.